# Best way to hang a lampshade

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a lampshade which looks like a demi-sphere but with irregular border. The goal is to hang it to the ceiling so that the border looks as horizontal as possible.

In order to formalize this, let us call $C$ the border of the lampshade, which forms a closed curve. We can choose a way to measure the distance from $C$ to a plane $P$, for instance:

- $d_\infty(C,P)=\max_{x\in C} d(x,P)$
- $d_1(C,P)=\int_{x\in C} d(x,P)$
- $d_2(C,P)= \left(\int_{x\in C} d(x,P)^2\right)^{1/2}$

Given a plane minimizing the distance, we can then choose the hanging point of the lampshade so that this plane is horizontal, for a good visual effect.

The question is: is there a unique plane $P$ minimizing the distance to $C$, or can there be several ?
An answer for any of $d_\infty$, $d_1$, $d_2$ would be satisfying.

Comment: Do you know that there is at least one such plane?  (You also might want to take the square root of your integral of the square, but, of course, that doesn't change the minimiser.)

Comment: Here is a proof scheme for existence of an optimal plane: for any orientation, you can compute the optimal plane with this orientation (i.e. you compare all translations of a reference plane), and clearly the optimal among those is reached by at least one plane. Then it amounts to optimizing the function Orientation -> Score. Since Orientations form a compact space, the optimal will be reached again by at least one particular orientation.
(and yes I omitted the square root since I just use $d_2$ for minimization, I expected the comment to pop up ^^)

Comment: If you relax the problem to allow the curve to be, say, the union of the three unit circles in the three coordinate planes (equator and meridians at right angles on a sphere), then there are too many symmetries, there can't be a unique minimizer. But I don't know if a simple closed curve can have enough symmetries to move every plane.

Comment: @ZachTeitler, thanks, yes with more relaxed hypotheses, I was also thinking of the edges of a cube as a counter-example